# VB.Net HttpClient GET request with authentication

Tags: .net, vb.net, http, http-headers

I have this snippet of code that I am wanting to use as a base for a call I need to make to a REST API GET request to return JSON data. I am able to call this and works fine. Now I am wanting to plug in the website I need. However, the site requires a username/password that I have. I just do not know exactly how to implement it in this situation. I am used to using WebRequest but saw it was recommended to use HttpClient.

```
Sub Main()
        ' Create new Task.
        ' ... Use AddressOf to reference a method.
        Dim t As Task = New Task(AddressOf DownloadPageAsync)
        ' Start the task.
        t.Start()
        ' Print a message as the page downloads.
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Async Sub DownloadPageAsync()
        Dim page As String = "http://en.wikipedia.org/"

        ' Use HttpClient in Using-statement.
        ' ... Use GetAsync to get the page data.
        Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
            Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(page)
                Using content As HttpContent = response.Content
                    ' Get contents of page as a String.
                    Dim result As String = Await content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    ' If data exists, print a substring.
                    If result IsNot Nothing And result.Length > 50 Then
                        Console.WriteLine(result.Substring(0, 50) + "...")
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: OT, you don't need three nested `Using` blocks there. Unless you have some code between them, there's no point using multiple `Using` blocks. A single `Using` statement can create multiple objects, simply by using commas between them.

Comment: The how to authenticate with the rest api depends a lot on the authentication method implemented by the rest api.  Your also just connecting to a webpage there, not making requests to a webapi so might want to clarify exactly what your trying to do.

Comment: @Hursey I am just trying to get a JSON response from a api website I am subscribed to. .net Isn't my main language I usually use for this but I have to use it in this scenario.

Comment: I must ask you how you implement/use this code. I read also MS docs and a few examples online and I understand you create a function...or method? what i don't understand is how you trigger/call that method. Say I have a winform and I want clicking a button to import the data into a textbox. How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code example from the documentation for the `HttpClientHandler` class:

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
   // Create an HttpClientHandler object and set to use default credentials
   HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
   handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

   // Create an HttpClient object
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

   // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
   try
   {
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");

      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
   }
   catch(HttpRequestException e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
       Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
   }

   // Need to call dispose on the HttpClient and HttpClientHandler objects
   // when done using them, so the app doesn't leak resources
   handler.Dispose();
   client.Dispose();
}
```

In this case, it is using the system default credentials but you can create a `NetworkCredential` yourself if you need to. That means that, in your code, you could change this:

```vb
Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    '...
End Using
```

to something like this:

```vb
Using handler As New HttpClientHandler With {.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)},
      client As New HttpClient(handler)
    '...
End Using
```

Comment: For the record, I have never done any of this myself - never used the `HttpClient` class - but I found this information by searching the web for "httpclient with credentials", reading some results and then reading the documentation for the types and members they mentioned. That's exactly what you should have done for yourself before posting this question. If I could find this information, you could too.